# Combinatorics Question - Help in Understanding?

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose $5$ students are to present only $4$ questions so that $2$ students need to present together. How many different ways you can arrange for the presentation?

I don't really understand the intuition or logic I should follow to solve this question.

I want to do $5C2$ initially, but I'm not sure what to do with the $4$. Can anyone explain it?

Thanks!

Comment: would the 4 questions be presented by distinct pairs of students?

Comment: Yes @AbishankaSaha

Comment: and two pairs are distinct if neither of the persons in one pair is present in another?

Answer (score 1):

I assume there are four different questions, and you need to assign two students to one question and one each to the other three; two assignments are different if any student is assigned to different questions.

In that case, you can start with ${}^5C_2$ ways to pair up two students. Now you have four groups of students (one pair and three singles), but you still need to decide which group is doing which question. There are $4!$ ways to assign groups to questions. So your answer is $4!\times{}^5C_2$

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how you know it's 4!? Why not a permutation formula?

Comment: It is a permutation formula: $4!={}^4P_4$. It's just the number of ways to order the $4$ groups of students - once you've ordered them you give the first group Q1 and so on.